# Gitlab change default branch for every project

Tags: gitlab

I am currently using GitLab Community Edition 9.0.0 and want to change default branch to "develop" for every project.

I know it can be done by project settings page but since we have almost 200 projects, is there easy way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Gitlab API to:

- Get a list of all the projects (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#list-projects))
- Loop on that list and edit every project to set the `default_branch` parameter (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#edit-project))

[Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/)'s more documentation on how to use the API.

You fist need to get a user's private token. Go to `http://<gitlab_domain>/profile/account` to get/generate one for your currently logged in user. You may want to do that as the gitlab administrator in order to have access to and be able to modify all those projects.

Then you need to generate the proper requests (see links above and [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/#basic-usage)).